# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND requirejs on cordova visual studio

Tags: javascript, requirejs, visual-studio-cordova

I'm developing an app on framework7 with cordova and Visual Studio 2015. In my project I use require js to load every controller, but when I debug on my phone , I get following errors:

http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror and

`Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND`

I can't understand because on the browser the app is working ok, has anyone else got the same problem?

I use route for valid what controller load, on my controllers I load like

```
require(['scripts/app/controllers/' + controllerName + '/' + controllerName + 'Controller'], function (controller) {
            controller.init(query);
        });
```

and my controller:

```
define(function () {
  var $ = Framework7.$;

  /**
  * Init router, that handle page events
  */
  function init() {

    $(document).on('pageBeforeInit', function (e) {
        var page = e.detail.page;

        load(page.name, page.query);
    });        
  }

  return {
    init: init
  };
});
```

Comment: Could you give a basic demo that can reproduce this problem?

Comment: define(function () {
    var query = {}, guid = localStorage.getItem("gid"), refresh = false;
    function refreshrows() {
       
    }

    function handlerRefresh() {
      
    }

    function init(q) {
   

    }



    return {
        init: init
    };
});